# How to pass the correct type via a generic in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

Say I have an array of objects and of the keys is called `render` which can be an optional function that takes a parameter (of which the type is unknown)

```
const array = [{a: 1}, {b: 2, render: renderFunction}, {c: 3, render: anotherFunction}]
```

say the 2nd object `renderFunction` takes a number as a param and `anotherFunction` takes a string as the param, how do I achieve that with generics?

```
const array: ArrayType<unknown> = [
  {a: 1},
  {b: 2, render: renderFunction} as MyType<number>,
  {c: 3, render: anotherFunction} as MyType<string>
]
```

but this doesn't work `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have only one key **'a'** other than render in Object.

You can define types like so:

```
interface ArrayItem {
    a: number;
    render?: <Type extends unknown>(arg: Type) => void;
}

const func1 = <Type extends unknown>(value: Type) => { };
const func2 = <Type extends unknown>(value: Type) => { };

const data: Array<ArrayItem> = [
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 2, render: func1 },
    { a: 3, render: func2 }
];

data[1].render?.<string>("test");
data[2].render?.<number>(23);
```

You can use above code for generics but to restrict parameter types you have to define custom type instead of unknow and extend it.

Comment: that's not possible unfortunately. I should have explained better. `param`. could literally be anything and I don't want to clutter that function with types I've created myself e.g. `param: string | number | myType | anotherOfMyTypes`. I want to use generics so that I can just tell it the type beforehand

Comment: I just updated my answer according to your needs. Let me know if this works fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best would be let TypeScript infer the type, just define `ArrayItem` as generic:

```
interface ArrayItem<T> {
    a: number;
    render?: (param: T) => void;
}
```

Then the parameter may be of any type:

```
const func1 = (value: string) => { };
const func2 = (value: number) => { };
```

And we remove the type definition from the assignment, in this way TypeScript will infer it:

```
const data = [
    { a: 1 } as ArrayItem<never>,
    { a: 2, render: func1 } as ArrayItem<string>,
    { a: 3, render: func2 } as ArrayItem<number>
] as const;
```

I added `as const` at the end in this way you'll tell TypeScript that each index of the array has a specific type, in this way the inferred type will be `[ArrayItem<never>, ArrayItem<string>, ArrayItem<number>]` and not `ArrayItem<string>[] | ArrayItem<number>[]`, which is more desirable.

In the end, you can just use it like:

```
data[1].render?.("test");
data[2].render?.(23);
```

And TypeScript will advise you the correct type for each element.

The answer was based on the one provided by @OsamaMalik

Comment: Hint: if you remove the `as const` you'll have to assert the type for each index

Comment: this looks good only issue I get now. is: `The type 'readonly .... ' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'ArrayItem<unknown>'`

Comment: Are you trying to use `.push`? You have to consider the object immutable and recreate the array each time you need to add an element. Otherwise you can remove `as const` but in this way you lose the type suggestions

Comment: Anyway your request is pretty complex, TypeScript tries its best but if you want it to "remember" the type for each index you have to provide immutability, otherwise any index may assume any type at any time :) just think what would happen if you do `data.sort()`, TypeScript cannot know it

Comment: nope not using push. just defined an array of objects and each object has the key render and I just want to define the type for that

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngSUgWwB4AVAPmQG8AoZW5OALmRAFd8AjaAbhrqghAATaAH4mACgAOcKPibEAlMgC85AG4B7YIJ4BfKlQQaQAZzDIYLEAgCMK5OLVwANiwhMzUUAHMlqysi6PEam5pbWAEz2ji5uTKwc0H7kFIE8hsZmyIJwYHD2ANq8tKmMyHa69CZoGNh4EEQgEGrQpAA0xQFlEW3I-ELQTOG2gVU1mLgEhJ4+7Z2lTADMvf3CUENWCFGVcNXoE-WNbJxQpFQAumMhZuk5eQU25wB0q6JP4gBEkGYfCjx3cAKEWerygIneEUWfwM13MZX2dSmMxA3nIymyuUBjy4QA)?